# null-space matrix multiplies invertible matrix is also null-space matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We define a matrix $Z$ to be a *null-space matrix* for $A$ if any vector in $N(A)$ (the null space of $A$) can be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of $Z$.

Let $Z$ be an $n\times  r$ null-space matrix for the matrix $A$. If $Y$ is any invertible $r\times r$ matrix, prove that $\hat{Z}=ZY$ is also a null-space matrix for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $Z$ is a null-space matrix for $A$ if and only if
$$
N(A)\subseteq \mbox{Ran} Z
$$
since the linear combinations of the columns of $Z$ are precisely the vectors in the range of $Z$.

Now if $Y$ is invertible, $Y(\mathbb{R}^r)=\mathbb{R}^r$, so
$$
\mbox{Ran}ZY=\mbox{Ran}Z.
$$

The result follows.

Comment: What is $ImZ$...?

Comment: @i_a_n The range of $Z$.

Comment: ...why $Y(\mathbb{R}^r)=\mathbb{R}^r$?

Comment: @i_a_n Because $Y$ is invertible, so in particular it is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be any vector in $N(A)$.

Then by the definition of nullspace matrix, there is a $w\in\mathbb{R}^r$ s.t. $Zw = v$. Because $Y$ is invertible, there is a $w'\in\mathbb{R}^r$ such that $w = Yw'$.

Therefore since there is a $w'$ such that $ZYw' = v$ for any $v\in N(A)$, $ZY$ is a nullspace matrix for $A$.